# Route multiple controllers to the same view and href

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page in which I want to load three controllers when the user clicks the link retrieve total data, I want the total data view to load three controllers.
I have done the following so far. But it only loads one controller. 
HTML

```
     <a  href="#/total" > Get Total Data </a></br></br>
<div ng-view style="position: absolute; text-align: left; ">>
 </div></p>
     </div>
     <div>
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="test.html">
  <h1 class= "tile tileLargo amarelo" >Total Places: {{places.places}}</h1>

  <h1 class= "tile tileLargo azul"  >Total Users: {{users.users}}</h1>


  <h1  >Total Coolios: {{coolios.coolios}}</h1>


  </script>
   </div>
```

Angular:
Route:

```
myApp .config(['$routeProvider',
 function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/total', {
    templateUrl: 'test.html',
    controller: 'TotalplacesCtrl'
  }).
    when('/total', {
    templateUrl: 'test.html',
    controller: 'TotalUserCtrl'
  }).  when('/total', {
    templateUrl: 'test.html',
    controller: 'TotalCoolioCtrl'
  }).
```

Contollers:

```
   myApp.controller('TotalUserCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

   $http.get('http://94.125.132.253:8001/gettotalusers').success(function (data) {

   $scope.users = data;
   console.log(data);
    }

     )});  //Total coolios

     myApp.controller('TotalCoolioCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
     $http.get('http://94.125.132.253:8001/gettotalcoolios').success(function (data) {
   $scope.coolios = data;
  console.log(data);
  }
  )}); 
  //Total coolios
  myApp.controller('TotalplacesCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

 $http.get('http://94.125.132.253:8001/gettotalplaces').success(function (data) {
 $scope.places = data;
 console.log(data);
  }
  )});
```

How can I fix it? I am very new to angular. But this is what I have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only your last route handler will fire in this case as each definition overwrites the last. There's a couple of alternatives I can think of - use the [UI Router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) and use nested states or specify the controller directly on each element that you want to render using that controller... E.g.

**Javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/total', {
        templateUrl: 'test.html',
        controller: 'TotalCtrl'
    });
}])
.controller('TotalCtrl', function($scope) {
})
.controller('TotalPlacesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.places = {
        places: 24
    };
})
.controller('TotalUsersCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.users = {
        users: 55
    };
})
.controller('TotalCooliosCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.coolios = {
        coolios: 18
    };
});
```

** Template **

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="test.html">
  <h1 ng-controller="TotalPlacesCtrl">Total Places: {{places.places}}</h1>
  <h1 ng-controller="TotalUsersCtrl">Total Users: {{users.users}}</h1>
  <h1 ng-controller="TotalCooliosCtrl">Total Coolios: {{coolios.coolios}}</h1>
</script>
```

Also [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/omUpEPwYNupd3BfScxjZ) to demonstrate.

Comment: So will this do what I want it to do? and what is the difference between this and UI-router

Comment: UI router works on the basis of states and isn't limited to just routes. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/ has further details. Only you can decide if this does what you want - I believe it does from your question. Did you try the Plunker?

Comment: Yes I have implemented it and it works, I was just worried that if this would affect anything in the long run.

Comment: Shouldn't do, it's the way they demonstrate it in the Angular docs - check out the **Associating Controllers with Angular Scope Objects** section at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller.

Comment: Okay thanks, One more question, I have similar situation, but I am requesting data by date where the user enters the date and presses fetch and I have linked all three controllers to the same form, so that when one fetch is pressed it performs all the functions from three controllers where fetch() is present in all three functions, how do I solve that.

Comment: I'm not sure this approach would solve that. Is there a reason you want to separate out the functionality like this? Is it purely separation of concerns? Perhaps investigate [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) and use a single controller which injects one or more services containing the functionality to fetch the data...